# how to make a significance bar in a figure ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(Names = c("Mine", "Mine", "Mine"), group = c("First", 
"Second", "Third"), median = c(10.011, 16.56, 18.21), SD = c(0.2345, 
0.3556, 0.037)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I plot it like this

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = median, color = Names)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(aes(group = Names), color = "black", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD))+
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("First", "Second", "Third"))
```

however, I want to put the line above it showing the significance

I have the *p* values as the second data like this

```
df2<- structure(list(Accession = "Mine ", Third_Second = 0.438, First_Second = 0.0234, 
    First_third = 0.035), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

and I want to make a figure like this if anyone has a comment ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option is to manually add the bars and asterisks

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)


sig_bar_1 <- tibble(x = c('First', 'First', 
                          'Third', 'Third'),
                    y = c(20,20.2,20.2,20))

sig_bar_2 <- tibble(x = c('Second','Second','Third','Third'),
                    y = c(19.5, 19.7, 19.7, 19.5))

sig_bar_3 <- tibble(x = c('First','First','Second','Second'),
                    y = c(19,19.2,19.2,19))

ggplot(df, aes(x = group, y = median, group = Names)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_line(color = "black", linetype="dashed") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = median - SD, ymax = median + SD))+
  scale_x_discrete(limit = c("First", "Second", "Third")) +
  geom_line(data = sig_bar_1,
            aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(data = sig_bar_2,
            aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1)) +
  geom_line(data = sig_bar_3,
            aes(x = x, y = y, group = 1)) +
  annotate('text', x = 2, y = 20.3, label = '*', size = 8) +
  annotate('text', x = 1.5, y = 19.3, label = '*', size = 8)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-31 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: how to define the y coordinate in `sig_bar_` ?

Comment: everything becomes black , is there a possibility to set the `color = Names`? like my figure ?